# Webkitforunboubdary error, formdata error, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm making a script where inside a function I use an xmlhttprequest to send a form data  However my request body is full of "webkitforunboubdary"

This is the body of the request being sent

```
"body": "------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER1\"\r\n\r\nIDPROD\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER2\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER3\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER4\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER5\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
 name=\"HEADER6\"\r\n\r\n106\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySRoy1hWZkwr3JfG3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
```

And this is my function to create the request

```
const comp_req =  (IDPROD) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('HEADER1', IDPROD);
        formData.append('HEADER2', '');
        formData.append('HEADER3', '');
        formData.append('HEADER4', '');
        formData.append('HEADER5', '');
        formData.append('HEADER6', '106');
        xhr.open('POST', 'URL_HERE', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () =>{
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    try{
                        console.log(xhr.responseText.sucess);
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).sucess);
                    } catch (error){
                        reject(false)
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.onerror = () => {
                reject(False)
            }  
        }
        xhr.send(formData);

    }).then(resolve => resolve)
      .catch(reject => reject)

}
```

Can anyone tell me why this web webkitforunboubdary is appearing all over the body, and how to fix the code so that it doesn't happen?

Comment: Check out the last answer in this post which describes what the webkitformboundary is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188903/what-does-webkitformboundary-mean
Note that it's pretty important to put the right syntax into your question, how did you end up with webkitforunboubdary ?!

Comment: You need to listen to `xhr.onload` instead of `xhr.onreadystatechange ` for simple form requests that does not involve files.