# Unable to generate Content-Type containing WebkitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxxx while uploading file using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on creating performance test for an application based on Windows authentication. Test plan is designed as following :

```
Test Plan
   HTTP Cookie Manager
   HTTP Authorization Manager
   Thread Group
       HTTP Request 1
       HTTP Request 2
```

One of the HTTP samplers is a file upload scenario. When I used Chrome to develop the script I observed that the when the file was uploaded a request header by name Content-Type was sent to the server. Request Header was similar to the following :

```
Content-Type = Multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebkitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I executed the script I observed that the Content-Type that JMeter generated is similar to 'multipart/form-data; boundary=RCQkexJjLBScxK26S_Rtp513mi4RFrEK4C' .
Please note the boundary part. Whereas the Content-Type that Chrome generated is similar to multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryslyIHy3AHA6pym8K I am not sure what is supposed to be done so that JMeter generates boundary having WebKitFormBoundary.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what is inside the boundary as long as you're using the same boundary in multiple parts of the [multipart request entity](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Here is an example from the RFC:

```
 From: Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com> 
 To:  Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com> 
 Subject: Sample message 
 MIME-Version: 1.0 
 Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple 
 boundary" 

 This is the preamble.  It is to be ignored, though it 
 is a handy place for mail composers to include an 
 explanatory note to non-MIME compliant readers. 
 --simple boundary 

 This is implicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It does NOT end with a linebreak. 
 --simple boundary 
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 

 This is explicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It DOES end with a linebreak. 

 --simple boundary-- 
 This is the epilogue.  It is also to be ignored.
```

Chrome generates boundaries containing [WebkitFormBoundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188903/what-does-webkitformboundary-mean) because Chrome is built on WebKit engine which Google borrowed from Apple and Apple in its turn borrowed this from [KHTML project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML)

It doesn't matter what the boundary is as long as it is not longer than 70 characters, has dashes in the beginning and so on

You have 2 options:

1. Set your own custom boundary containing whatever you want using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager). But in this case you will have to build your request body manually in the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler, use the defined boundary to split request parts, remember about line breaks and so on
2. Or just tick "Use multipart/form-data" in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and provide full or relative path to the file you want to upload in the "Files Upload" tab - JMeter will take care of the rest.